# Test modules inside modules in RSpec

Tags: rspec

I have this module inside another module:

```
module ParentModule
  module ChildModule
  end
end
```

I'd expect this to work:

```
describe ParentModule do
  describe ChildModule do
    it 'does something without crashing' do
      (1 + 1).should_be 2
    end
  end
end
```

And I get an error.

```
stack_overflow_q.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant ChildModule (NameError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec's `describe` method doesn't enter the scope of its argument.  `ChildModule` is only defined within the scope of `ParentModule`, so it's undefined when you reference it in the inner `describe`.

You could use `ParentModule::ChildModule` instead.

Comment: For some reason I thought I tried that before posting this question, but I didn't, that works, thanks!